# Using Two UITabBarControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am having problem with using two UITabBarController.
Which I have was :

**First UITabBarController with 2 tab (VC A and VC B)**

**Second UTabBarController with 4 tab (VC C , VC D and VC E , VC F)**.

When I make **push segue** from **VC B to Second UITabBarController(Starting at VC C)**,the first UITabBarController tab is still appearing.Any Help?

I am using Swift,so Swift help is appreciated.

How to use two UITabBarController at Storyboard?especially push segue from one TabBarController to another UITabBarController?

Please Help?I am stucking at there for hours.Really need a guide to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, it must be a problem in your implementation.

I created a new project of type *Tabbed Application*, and then added a second *Tab Bar Controller*. Then I added a push segue from a button in a view controller from the first tab bar, to the second tab bar, and it worked.

**Edit: It seems this is not possible when embedding your view controllers in a navigation controller.**

Comment: Mind give me a share project?

Comment: Ummm,your project is just a Single Tabbed Application created from Xcode.Not the one i mentioned.What i mean was from your project,it includes only One UITabBarController.Assume this you have Two UITabBarController at the storyboard and connect them with push segue and you will see.

Comment: You can check this out too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889901/uitabbarcontroller-push-segue-to-another-uitabbarcontroller. I left because nobody answer.So,I created simplest question.

Comment: I don't understand. My project *does* have two `UITabBarController`s. Does your segue go from a view controller to a `UITabBarController`? Or from one `UITabBarController` to another `UITabBarController`?

Comment: One UITabBarController to another UITabBarController,yes..please check my above question on comment,and you will see my storyboard

Comment: Can you download my project again? I fixed a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105829/discussion-between-6245htarwara-and-paulvs).